# version 1.7 of the jvm is not suitable for this product. version 1.8 greater is required for eclipse in window

Tags: java, eclipse

So what I Will do for that.
version 1.7 of the jvm is not suitable for this product. version 1.8 greater is required for eclipse nano in window
my system properties was 32 bit windows 7.
please let me explain What is the main reason.

Comment: Update Java SDK

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit. You are trying to run Eclipse with Java 1.7 but it requires at least Java 1.8. Either switch to a newer Java or an older Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download 1.8 JDK from Java SE Development Kit 8 Downloads install it, then copy the JRE folder & paste it in:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\EclipseNeon\"
```

Then rename the folder to "jre", start the eclipse again it should work.